# Flask and SQLAlchemy, not importing data from a new database table

Tags: python, mysql, flask, sqlalchemy

I have a working web app built with flask and MySQL database with SQLAlchemy.

As part of further development, I have created a new table in the database, called 'buggies'.
Previous tables in the database such as post were set up before the web was turned into a package, and I can still add and delete posts to this table.

However, the new table, called 'buggies' doesn't seem to be displaying the table contents on the home page - home.html.

Error log (excerpt):

```
Error running WSGI application
2020-04-17 08:29:28,946: jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: expected token 'end of print statement', got ':'
2020-04-17 08:29:28,946:   File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2309, in __call__
2020-04-17 08:29:28,946:     return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
```

I also do not seem to be able to connect to the database through SQLAlchemy, python3 in bash:

```
>>> from flask_app import db
>>> Post.query.all()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'Post' is not defined
>>> from flask_app.models import db
>>> Post.query.all()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'Post' is not defined

>>> from flask_app import db                                                                                                                                
>>> Buggies.query.all()                                                                                                                                     
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                                          
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>                                                                                                                       
NameError: name 'Buggies' is not defined                                                                                                                    
>>> from flask_app.models import db
>>> Buggies.query.all()                                                                                                                                     
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                                          
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>                                                                                                                       
NameError: name 'Buggies' is not defined                                                                                                                    
>>>
```

MySQL:

```
mysql> show tables;
+----------------------+
| Tables_in_olbliss$CF |
+----------------------+
| buggies              |
| post                 |
| user                 |
+----------------------+
3 rows in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> describe buggies;
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id           | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| BName        | varchar(100) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| BRider       | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| lastmodified | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
4 rows in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> select * from buggies;
+----+------------------+--------+---------------------+
| id | BName            | BRider | lastmodified        |
+----+------------------+--------+---------------------+
|  1 | Kawasaki         | Bob    | 2020-04-17 07:53:29 |
|  2 | Stewarding Buggy |        | 2020-04-17 07:55:50 |
|  3 | Parking Buggy    |        | 2020-04-17 07:56:10 |
+----+------------------+--------+---------------------+
3 rows in set (0.01 sec)

mysql>
```

**init**.py

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_bcrypt import Bcrypt
from flask_login import LoginManager

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["DEBUG"] = True

app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = '...'

SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = "mysql+mysqlconnector://{username}:{password}@{hostname}/{databasename}".format(
    username="xxxxx",
    password="xxxxx",
    hostname="xxxxx",
    databasename="xxxxx",
)
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_POOL_RECYCLE"] = 299
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS"] = False
db  = SQLAlchemy(app)
bcrypt = Bcrypt(app)
login_manager = LoginManager(app)
login_manager.login_view = 'login'
login_manager.login_message_category = 'info'

from flask_app import routes
```

routes.py

```
@app.route('/')
@app.route('/h')
@app.route('/home')
def home():
    posts = Post.query.all()
    buggies = Buggies.query.all()
    return render_template('home.html', posts=posts, buggies=buggies)
```

home.html (there isn't anything in layout.html which would cause a problem)

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block content %}
<p>{% for buggy in buggies %}
            {{ buggy:BName }}
        {% endfor %}</p>
{% endblock content %}
```

models.py

```
class Buggies(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    BName = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    BRider = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=True)
    lastmodified = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=True, default=datetime.utcnow)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Buggies('{self.BName}', '{self.BRider}','{self.lastmodified}')"

class Post(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    date_posted = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.utcnow)
    description = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
    status = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    assigned_to = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'), nullable=False)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Post('{self.title}', '{self.date_posted}')"
```

forms.py

```
class BuggyForm(FlaskForm):
    BName = StringField('Name of Buggy', validators=[DataRequired()])
    BRider = StringField('Name of Rider')
    lastmodified  = DateTimeField('Date and Time', format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    submit = SubmitField('Save')
```

Comment: there seems to be a jinja2 exception. can you show your html file

Comment: Thanks, it's given above, below the routes and above models. Thank you.

Comment: when you call buggies = Buggies.query.all() can you get all the elements in the list

Comment: check my answer

Comment: when I run Bggies.query.all() in python3 in bash, it says 'Buggies' is not defined. (it seems to be a connection issue to the databse, though, in other routes not shown in this question, I can successfully create and delete buggy rows in the web app into and out of the mysql database)

Comment: i meant to run the code block in the python file the file the init.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check the list use this code

```
for buggy in buggies:
    print(buggy.BName)
```

Also try changing your html to this:

```
<p>{% for buggy in buggies %}
            {{ buggy['BName'] }}
        {% endfor %}</p>
```

Comment: Changing the html file seems to have worked, I'll keep tesring it! Why would changing to ['BName'] work - out of interest? Also, adding the top code to __init__.py just crashes the site.